# So many if and else conditions

Tags: c#, typescript

I have this class

```
export class CurrentLanguageService {
  currentLanguage(loggedUser: User): string {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem(LanguageStorageKey) !== null) {
      if (Object.keys(Languages).includes(sessionStorage.getItem(LanguageStorageKey))) {
        return sessionStorage.getItem(LanguageStorageKey);
      } else {
        return Languages[Languages.nl];
      }
    } else {
      if (loggedUser.language) {
        return Languages[loggedUser.language];
      } else {
        return Languages[Languages.nl];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will see that I have so many conditions, is there a way that some one knows is this is proper coding, thanks

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as  [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/120114) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Does the [tag:c#] tag really apply, or is it just typescript? Also, it would benefit reviewers to have a bit more information about the code in the description. From [the help center page _How to ask_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "_You will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better._"

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the logic is correct. Why return the default language if there is a language corresponding to the language storage key but not contained in `Object.keys`? I'd think the language of the logged user to be the better alternative.

```
var language = sessionStorage.getItem(LanguageStorageKey);
if (language !== null && Object.keys(Languages).includes(language)) {
    return language;
} else if (loggedUser.language) {
    return Languages[loggedUser.language];
} else {
    return Languages[Languages.nl];
}
```

This simplification is possible due to these points:

1. Combining two conditions into one if-statement with `&&`. Note that Java Script (and thus TypeScript)  uses [short-circuit-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation). I.e., the second condition is only evaluated if the first is `true` (in the case of `&&`).
2. Testing the conditions in a sequential way instead of using nested if-statements.
3. Returning the default language (nl) at one place due to a better logic.
4. Storing the result of the call `sessionStorage.getItem(LanguageStorageKey)` into a temporary variable instead of performing the call three times. This leads not only to  a small performance gain but also makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

## Beautify

First thing that you need to do: apply refactoring [Extract variable](https://refactoring.guru/extract-variable).
This will make code cleaner & faster.

```
const storedLanguage = sessionStorage.getItem(LanguageStorageKey);
if (storedLanguage !== null) {
    if (Object.keys(Languages).includes(storedLanguage)) {
        return storedLanguage;
    } else {
        return Languages[Languages.nl];
    }
} else {
    …
}
```

After that let's get rid of if-s by applying [Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses](https://refactoring.guru/replace-nested-conditional-with-guard-clauses)

```
const storedLanguage = sessionStorage.getItem(LanguageStorageKey);
if (storedLanguage !== null && Object.keys(Languages).includes(storedLanguage)) {
    return storedLanguage;
}

if (loggedUser.language) {
    return Languages[loggedUser.language];
}

return Languages[Languages.nl];
```

And now we can use [Nullish Coalescing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) operator to simplify our code

```
const storedLanguage = sessionStorage.getItem(LanguageStorageKey);
if (storedLanguage !== null && Object.keys(Languages).includes(storedLanguage)) {
    return storedLanguage;
}

return Languages[loggedUser.language ?? Languages.nl];
```

Now, I would suggest to leverage `in`-syntax to make things shorter:

```
if (storedLanguage !== null && storedLanguage in Languages) {
    …
```

Next trick can be considered bad in some code styles. Typically, typescript will deny you to perform check like `null in smth`, because of typing. But he is wrong here.
We can use [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

```
const storedLanguage = sessionStorage.getItem(LanguageStorageKey);
if (storedLanguage! in Languages) {
    return storedLanguage;
}

return Languages[loggedUser.language ?? Languages.nl];
```

## Same level of abstraction

Let's make things more clear. You are checking that storedLanguage is in enum.
Let's build utility function for it

```
function keepIfInEnum<T>(
    value: string,
    enumObject: { [key: string]: T }
) {
    if (Object.values(enumObject).includes((value as unknown) as T)) {
        return (value as unknown) as T;
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

Now we can write:

```
return keepIfInEnum(sessionStorage.getItem(LanguageStorageKey)) 
    ?? Languages[loggedUser.language ?? Languages.nl];
```